# php update accepts only numbers how to input text and numbers

Tags: php

Hi i use this php script to update some values in my database but it accepts only numbers when i put my email it says : Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com' at line 1

i want to update the values where by entering email and username

and increase the values because i have more than 5 values to update

any solution? :)

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'root';

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $gold = $_POST['gold'];

            $sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold ". 
               "WHERE email = $email" ;
            mysql_select_db('chickenstories');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);
         }else {
            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Email : </td>
                        <td><input name = "email" type = "text" 
                           id = "email"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Gold : </td>
                        <td><input name = "gold" type = "text" 
                           id = "gold"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
            <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not putting email as string, you are passing it without escaping it, update this line:

`$sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold ". "WHERE email = $email" ;`

to Be:

`$sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold ". "WHERE email = '$email'" ;`

I also recommend you to escape all variable before putting them in database, to avoid  SQL injection.

Comment: one small update i need is it possible to update the query by email and username? something like $sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold ". "WHERE email = '$email' and username = '$username'" ;

Comment: yes it is possible, you wrote the query correct, you just need to have the username  variable and you are good to go.

Comment: i have changed the query but i get a syndax error    $sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold, chickens = $chickens". "WHERE email = '$email' and username = '$username'" ;

Comment: use this $sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = '$gold', chickens = '$chickens'". " WHERE email = '$email' and username = '$username'" ;

Answer (score -1):

now it dont work again i have somewhere a syntax error on my query

Could not update data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'email = 'test@hotmail.com' and username = 'TestName'' at line 1

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'root';

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $gold = $_POST['gold'];
            $chickens = $_POST['chickens'];





            $sql = "UPDATE userdata ". "SET gold = $gold, chickens = $chickens". "WHERE email = '$email' and username = '$username'" ;
            mysql_select_db('chickenstories');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);
         }else {
            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Email : </td>
                        <td><input name = "email" type = "text" 
                           id = "email"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Username : </td>
                        <td><input name = "username" type = "text" 
                           id = "username"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Gold : </td>
                        <td><input name = "gold" type = "text" 
                           id = "gold"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">Chickens : </td>
                        <td><input name = "chickens" type = "text" 
                           id = "chickens"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
            <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```